# Binding custom Dependency Property to ListView width not updating

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have an `IValueConverter` named `CategoryToGridViewConverter` which has a DependencyProperty named `ListViewWidthProperty`. I have also inherited my converter from `DependencyObject` so that it will work with DependencyProperties. Here is how my converter is defined:

```
internal class CategoryToGridViewConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ListViewWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListViewWidth", typeof (double),
                                                                                                      typeof (CategoryToGridViewConverter), new PropertyMetadata(0d, PropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ListViewWidth: " + dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue);
        }

        public double ListViewWidth {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ListViewWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ListViewWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Not relevant
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Not relevant
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty simple. Then I am creating this converter in XAML (In ListView Resources section) like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategory.Entries}"
          x:Name="listView"
          SizeChanged="ListView_OnSizeChanged">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:CategoryToGridViewConverter x:Key="CategoryToGridViewConverter" ListViewWidth="{Binding listView, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <Binding Path="SelectedCategory" Converter="{StaticResource CategoryToGridViewConverter}"/>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But the problem is that `ListViewWidth` never updates. It always stays at 0. But the ListView in question is obviously not having 0 width.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It also gives a binding error on output screen:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Width; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'CategoryToGridViewConverter' (HashCode=33594544); target property is
>   'ListViewWidth' (type 'Double')

Does DependencyProperties only work for FrameworkElements? If so, how will my converter get to know about ListView's width?

Comment: A `DependencyProperty` can only be declared in a `DependencyObject` as far as I know. That is the class that gives you `SetValue` and `GetValue` for example. I don't really get how is this compiling if you only have an `IValueConverter` interface for `CategoryToGridViewConverter`. Could you please update your answer with the full implementation of the converter?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Thanks, and can you please insert the usage of the converter as well? I can see you are putting it into a `Resources` collection or `ResourceDictionary`, but where do you want to use it?

Comment: I have updated it again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use a multi-value converter.

```
<local:CategoryToGridViewMultiConverter x:Key="CategoryToGridViewConverter" />
```

The converter:

```
public class CategoryToGridViewMultiConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var category = (Category)values[0]; // Assumption: you're using a class named Category
        var listViewWidth = (double)values[1];

        // same logic you had before
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ListView.View>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CategoryToGridViewConverter}">
        <Binding Path="SelectedCategory" />
        <Binding ElementName="listView" Path="Width" Mode="OneWay" />
    </MultiBinding>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. Do you know why the other method didn't work?

Comment: I think, it's because the converter is not part of the visual or logical tree, the binding in the `ResourceDictionary` doesn't know which `FrameworkElement`'s `DataContext` to use to evaluate the bindings against. As described here: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/